# Stripping 'get_the_author_link' to only return the URL (not name, title, target etc)

Tags: wordpress

The code will return a lof of unnecessary information. This is not needed and breaks my icon.

Tried placing the code inside an href tag. It broke it.

It does work alone since it then returns the name of the person, and makes the name clickable to his website. But I only want it to return the website URL. Not the name, etc.

```
<?php echo get_the_author_link(); ?>
```

when used like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_the_author_link(); ?>" target="_blank"><li><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></li></a>
```

it outputs the following too crowded (and broken) code:

```
<a href="//www.linkedin.com/in/name-of-person-16010487&quot; title=&quot;Visit name's site&quot; rel=&quot;author external&quot;&gt;Name of Person&lt;/a&gt;" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><li><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></li></a>
```

All i basically want it to return is the URL, not the name etc. which breaks the output.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
<?php
$author_data = get_userdata( $author->ID );
?>

<li>
  <a href="<?php echo $author_data->user_url; ?>" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_the_author_link_url(){
    $author_url = get_the_author_meta('url');
    return !empty( $author_url )? $author_url : false;
}
```

you can use this function to get the url, if set or false otherwise. Please make sure to check if the result is false or alter it to fit your needs.

Inspired by the [Documentation for get_the_author_link()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_link/)